# HTML form not populating MySQL DB as expected

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I save a form from html to php and finally store it in MySQL somewhere in that line it save the `var=` including what comes after the `=`

Here is my html:

```
   <form action="searchResultsSave.php" method="POST">
     What are we looking for? <input type="text" name="searchVar" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

Php:

```
    $searchVar = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO g_information(searchVar) VALUES ('$searchVar')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Finally my output in mysql is: "searchVar=cars" when it should just be "cars".

Where do you think I went wrong?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I am not a PHP person, it should be $_POST['searchVar'] not all the post params....

Comment: Why use the input stream? Use parameterized queries would be better. Please only tag languages being used.

Comment: What is the purpose of `file_get_contents()` and `"php://input"` where no file object is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

```
$searchVar = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

should be

```
$searchVar = $_POST['searchVar'];
```

This way you get the value of the search term.

Answer (score 1):

You should read input variable from the form

```
    <?php
    $_POST["searchVar"];
    ?>
```

Then do some validation on the input, making sure no illegal characters are entered and data is safe to store in MySQL database

```
    <?php
    $_POST['searchVar'] = filter_var($_POST['searchVar'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO g_information(searchVar) VALUES ("'.$_POST['searchVar'].'")"; 
    ?>
```